# How to get xml tag with wildcard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

**xml**

```
<content-body-par jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys">
<text jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:created="2015-10-16T11:23:30.098+08:00" jcr:createdBy="admin" jcr:lastModified="2015-10-16T11:23:42.576+08:00" jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin" sling:resourceType="altera-www/components/general/text" text="<p>mekon</p> " textType="richtext"/>
<mekon jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:created="2015-10-16T10:33:19.218+08:00" jcr:createdBy="admin" jcr:lastModified="2015-10-16T10:33:56.915+08:00" jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin" pubId="00014864-AA" sling:resourceType="altera-www/components/dynamic-modules/mekon" topicId="AA00013077"/>
<mekon_0 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:created="2015-10-16T11:10:39.230+08:00" jcr:createdBy="admin" jcr:lastModified="2015-10-16T11:10:54.502+08:00" jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin" pubId="000003016-aa" sling:resourceType="altera-www/components/dynamic-modules/mekon" topicId="000003016-aa"/>
<sightly_demandpdf jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:created="2015-10-14T10:28:09.397+08:00" jcr:createdBy="admin" jcr:lastModified="2015-10-14T10:28:09.397+08:00" jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin" sling:resourceType="altera-www/components/included/sightly-demandpdf"/>
</content-body-par>
</jcr:content>
```

I would want to get the mekon tag using javascript/jquery. If you look at the xml tags above, there are **mekon** and **mekon_0**. How do I get the jrc:created attribute value from **mekon** tag?

The desired result should be **2015-10-16T10:33:19.218+08:00** and **2015-10-16T11:10:39.230+08:00**

I have tried this

```
alert($(doc).find('mekon').attr('jcr:created'));
```

but it only able to output **2015-10-16T10:33:19.218+08:00**  :(

Comment: try `var values = $(doc).find('*').filter(function(){
    return /^mekon/.test(this.nodeName);
}).map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('jcr:lastModified')
}).get();`

Comment: or `var values = $(doc).find('[jcr\\:lastModified]').filter(function(){
    return /^mekon/.test(this.nodeName);
}).map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('jcr:lastModified')
}).get();`

Comment: i copy your codes and alert(values) , what i get is repeated alert with empty string :(

Answer (score 0):

After numerous time of trying, I got the desire results

```
    var results = $(doc).find('*').filter(function(){
        return this.nodeName.match(/^mekon/i);
    }).map(function(){ return $(this).attr('jcr:created');});


    $.each(results, function(index, value){
        alert(index + " " + value);
    });
```

Thanks @Arun P Johny for the idea :)